# How to build SNAP package from Qt project

Tags: qt, ubuntu, snapcraft

It's my first time then I build a program into the SNAP package. I want to make my program more accessible.
The build is going without problems.
But libqtnetwor5 not see a couple needed libraries. Right here below you can see description of all logs and configurations.

The project tree:

```
tree
.
├── bin
│   └── ProjectTimer
├── setup
│   └── gui
│       └── icon.png
├── snapcraft.yaml
└── timerproject_1.0_amd64.snap

3 directories, 4 files
```

snapcraft.yaml

```
name: timerproject
version: "1.0"
summary: timer
description: |
    Application for time-management
confinement: strict
architectures: [amd64]

apps:
    timerproject:
        command: desktop-launch ProjectTimer
        plugs: ['home', 'unity7', 'x11', 'network']

parts:
    timerproject:
        plugin: copy
        files:
            bin/ProjectTimer : usr/bin/ProjectTimer
            setup/gui/icon.png : usr/share/icons/timer.ico

    integration:
        plugin: nil
        stage-packages:
            - libc-bin
            - libqt5network5
        after: [desktop/qt5]
```

ldd ProjectTimer shows all libreries that the program need:

```
ldd bin/ProjectTimer
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1f1fc000)
    libQt5QuickControls2.so.5 => /media/free/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5QuickControls2.so.5 (0x00007f5d2ad62000)
    libQt5Quick.so.5 => /media/free/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5 (0x00007f5d2a772000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /media/free/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f5d29f22000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /media/free/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f5d2977a000)
    libQt5Qml.so.5 => /media/free/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5 (0x00007f5d2917a000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /media/free/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f5d28a5a000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f5d286b2000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5d2849a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5d280ca000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /media/free/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f5d27d6a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5d27b4a000)
    libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5 => /media/free/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5 (0x00007f5d27882000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f5d275f2000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5d272e2000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f5d270c2000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f5d26eba000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000562df3108000)
    libicui18n.so.56 => /media/free/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007f5d26a1a000)
    libicuuc.so.56 => /media/free/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007f5d26662000)
    libicudata.so.56 => /media/free/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007f5d24c7a000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5d24a72000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5d2486a000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5d24552000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f5d2431a000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f5d24032000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f5d23dc2000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f5d23a82000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f5d2386a000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f5d23642000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f5d2343a000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f5d23232000)
```

If I start to program, I see message:
    timerproject
    ProjectTimer: /snap/timerproject/x1/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found 
        (required by /snap/timerproject/x1/media/free/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5)
    ProjectTimer: /snap/timerproject/x1/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5: version`Qt_5' not found 
        (required by /snap/timerproject/x1/media/free/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5)

This is libraries for SNAP package:

```
ls -l /snap/timerproject/x1/media/free/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 25047100 янв 28  2016 libicudata.so.56
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3374854 янв 28  2016 libicui18n.so.56
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2070162 янв 28  2016 libicuuc.so.56
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5339752 июл 30 16:45 libQt5Core.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5909528 июн 10 12:10 libQt5Gui.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4156520 июн 11 17:18 libQt5Qml.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    78696 июн 13 00:46 libQt5QuickControls2.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4125768 июн 11 17:18 libQt5Quick.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   807600 июн 13 00:46 libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6614408 июн 10 12:10 libQt5Widgets.so.5
```

My system have in standard libraries Qt:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1014 май  2 15:37 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.prl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       19 май  2 15:39 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so -> libQt5Core.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       19 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 -> libQt5Core.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       19 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.5 -> libQt5Core.so.5.5.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5052920 май  2 15:41 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.5.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1008 май  2 15:37 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.prl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       19 май  2 15:39 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so -> libQt5DBus.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       19 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5 -> libQt5DBus.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       19 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5.5 -> libQt5DBus.so.5.5.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   509456 май  2 15:41 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       23 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Feedback.so.5 -> libQt5Feedback.so.5.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       23 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Feedback.so.5.0 -> libQt5Feedback.so.5.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    52144 мар 14 14:20 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Feedback.so.5.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1039 май  2 15:37 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.prl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       18 май  2 15:39 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so -> libQt5Gui.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       18 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 -> libQt5Gui.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       18 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5.5 -> libQt5Gui.so.5.5.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5514016 май  2 15:41 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5.5.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1002 май  2 15:37 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.prl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       22 май  2 15:39 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so -> libQt5Network.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       22 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 -> libQt5Network.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       22 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5.5 -> libQt5Network.so.5.5.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1412480 май  2 15:41 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5.5.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1266500 май  2 15:41 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGLExtensions.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1056 май  2 15:37 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGLExtensions.prl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       21 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5 -> libQt5OpenGL.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       21 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.5 -> libQt5OpenGL.so.5.5.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   362752 май  2 15:41 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       18 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5 -> libQt5Qml.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       18 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5.5 -> libQt5Qml.so.5.5.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4358744 апр 12 13:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5 -> libQt5Quick.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5.5 -> libQt5Quick.so.5.5.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3991248 апр 12 13:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       24 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5QuickTest.so.5 -> libQt5QuickTest.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       24 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5QuickTest.so.5.5 -> libQt5QuickTest.so.5.5.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   119232 апр 12 13:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5QuickTest.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       21 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKit.so.5 -> libQt5WebKit.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       21 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKit.so.5.5 -> libQt5WebKit.so.5.5.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 37857816 ноя 30  2015 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKit.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       28 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5 -> libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       28 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5.5 -> libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5.5.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   282016 ноя 30  2015 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5.5.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1059 май  2 15:37 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.prl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       22 май  2 15:39 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so -> libQt5Widgets.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       22 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 -> libQt5Widgets.so.5.5.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       22 июл 29 22:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.5 -> libQt5Widgets.so.5.5.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6861328 май  2 15:41 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.5.1
```

Maybe someone can understand where is the error? Or maybe someone can tell me how better to deal with libraries (my project not used a system libraries)
And last question, but not least does someone know how to build Qt projects like this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're mixing Qt libraries from your own build and from your distribution (presumably, Ubuntu). The binary you're building depends on one Qt library (which you get from your own Qt build) and that one in turn depends on another Qt library that you get from Ubuntu. So the solution to this problem is to use only one source for Qt libraries.

I'd probably go for distribution libraries, unless there are some very specific reasons for using your own. To do it this way you need to fix your binary compilation (there are not enough details about it at the moment) to not link with your libraries (`-I` and `-L` flags, `-rpath` and similar things), everything else should be done automatically.

To package your own libraries you need to build them with `-rpath` flag so that dependencies for one library would also be resolved in your libraries directory. From what I see, snapcraft should be able to pick them in this case.